# Not reading all media query

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have the following CSS in my stylesheet:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .entry-title, .entry-title a {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    a.more-link {
        width: 44%;
    }
    .entry-title, .entry-header .entry-meta {
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
} 

@media only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 380px) {
    .entry-title, .entry-title a {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    a.more.link {
        width: 45%;
    }
    .entry-title, .entry-header .entry-meta {
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 330px) {
    .entry-title, .entry-title a {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    a.more-link {
        width: 52%;
    }
    .entry-title, .entry-header .entry-meta {    
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

}
```

When I go to test the middle query `(max-width: 380px)` it isn't being read by the browser. Instead its reading the first query `(max-width: 420px)`. If I remove the fist media query, it then the browser only reads the last media query `(max-width: 330px)`.

I also have this in the `header.php` file:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Missing more information, but I see `a.more.link` in your middle media query and `a.more-link` on your other two.  I'm guessing it should be the latter.

Comment: Also, there is no need to repeat `.entry-title, .entry-title a` and `.entry-title, .entry-header .entry-meta` in your other media queries - they will inherit the font-size and padding from the first one since they are all identical values.

Comment: The CSS code is not enough to help you. Please post some HTML code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the second one: Should be `a.more-link` instead of   `a.more.link`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change first media query with

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) and (min-width: 380px)
```